# JQuery hide / show not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

New to this, trying to muddle my way through, is there anything wrong with the code? Lines 1-8 work, then the button won't continue to the next div.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#personal-info, #cc-sub').hide()

    $('.amount_radio_button').click(function() {
        $('#donation-amount').hide('fast') 
        $('#personal-info').show('slow')

        $('.nextBtn1').click(function() {
            $('#personal-info').hide('fast') 
            $('#cc-sub').show('slow')

            $('#submit').click(function() {
                $('#cc-sub').hide('slow') 
                $('#thank_you').show('slow')    
            });                     
        });                     
    });     
});
```

Comment: Obamas?  Tell me you're not trying to re-create healthcare.gov...

Comment: @AdamRackis well according to OP lines 1-8 work so he's already exceeded that goal.

Comment: I think I remember helping one of their programmers last week. It began with "I'm a PHP noob."

Comment: You should not usually define click handlers inside other click handlers.

Comment: Which are lines 1-8? I got rid of lots of unnecessary blank lines when I reformatted your code.

Comment: "creating a donation site similar to obamas Jquery issue" is not a problem title.  Can you tell us what problem you're having? For instance, "Jquery hide / show is not working?" (or whatever your particular problem actually is).

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up your event handlers beside each other, not nested in one another. Currently the event handler will only get registered with the other events are fired. Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#personal-info, #cc-sub').hide()

    $('.amount_radio_button').click(function() {
        $('#donation-amount').hide('fast') 
        $('#personal-info').show('slow')
    });     

    $('.nextBtn1').click(function() {
        $('#personal-info').hide('fast') 
        $('#cc-sub').show('slow')                    
    });   

    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $('#cc-sub').hide('slow') 
        $('#thank_you').show('slow')    
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you're nesting your event handlers. You have to define them separately, not inside each other.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#personal-info, #cc-sub').hide();

    // hide the donation amount, show person info next
    $('.amount_radio_button').click(function() {
        $('#donation-amount').hide('fast');
        $('#personal-info').show('slow');
    });     

    // hide personal info, show subscription info
    $('.nextBtn1').click(function() {
        $('#personal-info').hide('fast');
        $('#cc-sub').show('slow');
    });

    // hide subscription info, show thank you section
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $('#cc-sub').hide('slow');
        $('#thank_you').show('slow');
    });

});
```